# Initialize or Lazy load an ObservableCollection<T> in a fast and optimized way from IEnumerable<T> records

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ienumerable, observablecollection

I have an `IEnumerable<T>` collection of about 30,000 records that are created upon application load time and these records are converted to `ObservableCollection<T>` by doing (which takes substantial amount to load WPF application):

```
IEnumerable<Person> enumerablePeople; //Initialized and contains around 30,000 records
ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>(enumerablePeople);
```

Is there some different optimized or fast method / way other than newing up I can use or if possible can I use some kind of *Lazy loading* to initialize it, to convert `IEnumerable<Person>` to `ObservableCollection<Person>` so that it loads the collection / application faster.

Comment: Is it the populating of the collection that takes too long, or is the collection already bound to some element (causing the ui to create and render 30000 elements)?

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt The new operation of the ObservableCollection<T> takes more time and may be this is also because the collection is bound to WPF datagrid. Do you want to say we should not bound it to WPF datagrid when the collection is initialized?

Comment: No. There is no faster method to do this.

Comment: @VS1: Well, presumably the collection has to be bound to the grid at one point. So your only hope is to find a *smart* grid that can virtualize its contents.

Comment: I changed your C# and .NET tags to the more generic ones to help more people see the question.

Comment: It seems to me that bound of interface grid to 30000 records collection is not so good idea. And  i suppose, your users don't want to see grid with 30000 rows, is it?

Comment: @VS1: Or indeed, as Kirll suggests, trimming the actual amount of data to a manageable quantity.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Virtualizing is a way to go but as I am using a third party datagrid which doesn't allow virtualization.

Comment: How long does that new take?   Why are you not loading directly into the ObservableCollection?  Why not bind the UI to IEnumerable<Person>?

Comment: What is the nature of the IEnumerable<Person>?  Is it from a WCF Service proxy or something like that?  If so then the majority of the time spent in the ObservableCollection<Person> ctor might be from pulling those 30K people down from the server and not actually in creating the ObservableCollection<Person>.

Comment: @RaySaltrelli the WCF service proxy returns all 30000 records in one go, and then on the UI they are converted to ObservableCollection.

Comment: Yes but the question is "When are those 30K Person objects actually downloaded?"  IEnumerable<Person> might not actually contain those Person objects until you attempt to enumerate over them and if the first time you do that is within the ObservableCollection<Person> ctor then that would explain why the ctor is taking so long.  It not only has to create the ObservableCollection<T>, it has to download the 30K Person objects first.

Comment: No records are not converted to ObservableCollection in the UI.  How are you sure you have the full enumerablePeople rather than deferred processing?   Try this right after you "create" enumerablePeople:                      Debug.WriteLine(enumerablePeople.Count().ToString());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only method `IEnumerable` allows to access its contents is to enumerate though them one by one. If your `IEnumerable` is available as a `List` it *might* be able to grab the internal array, though I expect you'll end up having to copy all the contents regardless.

30000 references should not take very long to copy. If it is taking more than a second or two, I'd make sure it's not calling some slow event handlers or updating the UI for every item added.

Comment: The `ObservableCollection<T>` constructor that takes in the `IEnumerable<T>` stream immediately iterates and copies the contents of the stream to its internal list. This means that supplying an `ObservableCollection<T>` with an `IEnumerable<T>` does ***not*** allow the stream to be lazy loaded.

Answer (score -1):

People are trying to help you and you are not listening.

Just how are you "creating" an?

```
IEnumerable<T>
```

Can not new an IEnumerable
This syntax fails

```
IEnumerable<Person> IPeople = new IEnumerable<Person>();
```

You may be creating a reference to an IEnumerable in the application load.
But you are NOT creating an IEnumerable object as there is no such thing.
IEnumerable is an interface not a collection - it cannot be newed.

See code below.
Created an ObservableCollection of 100,000 from IEnumerable ctor in 16 ms.

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(iPeople.Count().ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());  // 13 ms
sw.Restart();
ObservableCollection<Person> ocPeople = new ObservableCollection<Person>(iPeople);         
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());  // 16 ms
sw.Restart();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(iPeople.Count().ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());  //  8 ms
sw.Restart();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ocPeople.Count().ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());  //  1 ms
sw.Restart();
List<Person> lPeople = new List<Person>(iPeople);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());  // 10 ms
sw.Restart();
ObservableCollection<Person> ocPeople2new = new ObservableCollection<Person>(lPeople);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());  //  6 ms

public IEnumerable<Person> iPeople
{
    get
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) yield return new Person(i);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public Int32 ID { get; private set; }
    public Person(Int32 id) { ID = id; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry.. to make it clear late.. but IEnumerable<T> is returned as a List<T> from the WCF service filled with all the records and I only convert it using this code: `ObservableCollection<T> people = new ObservableCollection<T> (enumerablePersons);`

Comment: Then fix the question.   No way it takes ObservableCollection 30 seconds to initialize from a populated local List.  I did 100,000 from List is 6 ms.  Post code to reproduce the problem.